# Google sheets REGEXREPLACE() replace text with itself

Tags: regex, replace, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In Google Sheets, I'd like to replace the following text:

`The ANS consists of fibers that stimulate ((1smooth muscle)), ((2cardiac muscle)), and ((3glandular cells)).`

with this text below:

`The ANS consists of fibers that stimulate {{c1::smooth muscle}}, {{c2::cardiac muscle}}, and {{c3::glandular cells}}.`

I know if I use `=REGEXREPLACE(E3, "\(\([0-9]*", "{{c::")` I can get here:

`The ANS consists of fibers that stimulate {{c::smooth muscle)), {{c::cardiac muscle)), and {{c::glandular cells)).`

BUT I don't know how to keep the original numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm, figured it out.

Putting parentheses around the term allows you to reference it again in your replacement string.

For example, my solution for my problem was this:

`=REGEXREPLACE(E3, "\(\(([0-9]*)", "{{c$1::")`

This works because putting `[0-9]*` in parentheses like so: `([0-9]*)` allowed it to be referenced as `$1` in my substitution string.

I assume that if I had another phrase enclosed in parentheses after that it would be able to be referenced with `$2`.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Pass 1:

Search Pattern:(((\d)(.+)

Replacement:{{C$1::$2

Pass 2:

Search Pattern: ))

Replacment: }}

I played around with it some more and this will do it in one pass:

Search Pattern: `\(\((\d)(.+?)\b\)\)`

Replacements:  `{{C$1::$2}}`